# RSS doesn't render in React component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, architecture, rss

I am trying to display a RSS widget on my website and I am trying to render it from my React component. But it doesn't show up. When I tried to add it to my HTML file, at the bottom of  it works perfect.

How should I go about adding script tags to React?

This is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Blog extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1 className="page-header">Blog</h1>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://feed.mikle.com/js/fw-loader.js" data-fw-param="52132/"></script>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Blog;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try loading the `<script>` outside of your `render` method and moving it into a lifecycle method instead - that is, unless you want the script to load every time the `render` method gets called. Try something like this:

```
componentWillMount() {

    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "https://use.typekit.net/foobar.js";

    // you may want to load the script asynchronously so that is is
    // only executed once available
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

This way, your `<script>` should get called just before your component mounts.